# Joining tables in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, join

I have been trying to solve the following problem using Core Data without any luck.

My model has two entities:Group and Element. Both with a "name" attribute and a to-many relationship in the form of: "group.elements" and "element.groups" (a Element belonging to several Groups and a Group having several Elements)

I want to establish a "filter" in the form of:

`elements that belongs to "group_A" AND "group_B"`

In order to show to the user something like:

`The elements that match the filter belong to this set of groups in that quantity`

As an example, having something like:

> Element_1    Group_A, Group_B, Group_C
>   Element_2    Group_B, Group_C
>   Element_3    Group_A, Group_B, Group_D
>   Element_4    Group_A, Group_B, Group_D
>   Element_5    Group_C, Group_D

The answer should be: Element_1, Element_3 and Element_4 match the filter and the information to be shown would be like:

> Group_A has 3 elements
> Group_B has 3 elements
> Group_C has 1 element
> Group_D has 2 elements
> That match the filter

How could I put this in Core Data NSExpression, NSPredicate etc.?

Thanks.

## UPDATE

I think I found two ways of solving this.

### Option 1

This option establishes an NSArray with the "group's names filter" and returns all the groups with the number of elements they have that match the condition EVEN THOUGH it's zero (no elements match)

There are two entities, "Grp" and "Elem", with a to-many relationship between them.

```
NSError *error = nil;

// Properties to be fetched
NSPropertyDescription *namePropDesc = [[[[self.moModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Grp"] propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"];

// Variable group filter
NSArray *grpFilter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"group_A", @"group_B", nil];

// Expression for counting elements
NSExpressionDescription *countExprDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[countExprDesc setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(elems,$elem, SUBQUERY($elem.grps, $grp, $grp.name in %@).@count==%d).@count", grpFilter, grpFilter.count]];
[countExprDesc setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];
[countExprDesc setName:@"elementCount"];

// Create data fetching and set its properties
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Grp"];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:namePropDesc,countExprDesc, nil]];

NSArray *results = [self.moContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"results = %@"results);
```

### Option 2

This option establishes an NSArray with the "group's names filter" and returns all the groups with the number of elements they have that match the condition WITHOUT THOSE groups that don't have any elements.

In this case, I created three entities, Grp, Elem and RGE. Having RGE as an intermediate entity that keeps the to-many relationships with the two other. This option allows to put some extra information in the group-element association (creation date, etc.) if needed. Grp and Elem don't have a relationship between each other.

***Note**: In fact, I neened to create a "regular" field (name) in the RGE entity to apply the @count function. If a "to-many relationship field" is used it fails to count properly.*

```
NSError *error = nil;


// Variable group filter
NSArray *grpFilter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"group_A", @"group_B", nil];

// Create variable predicate string from "group's names filter"
NSMutableString *predicateStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(int n=0;n<grpFilter.count;n++) {
    if(n>0) {
        [predicateStr appendString:@" AND "];
    }
    [predicateStr appendString:@"(ANY elem.rges.grp.name=%@)"];
}

// Filter to be applied
NSPredicate *filterQuery = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateStr argumentArray:grpFilter];

// Expression for counting elements
NSExpressionDescription *countExprDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[countExprDesc setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"name.@count"]];
[countExprDesc setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];
[countExprDesc setName:@"count"];

// Expression for grouping JUST by the group's name
NSExpressionDescription *grpNameExprDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[grpNameExprDesc setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"grp.name"]];
[grpNameExprDesc setExpressionResultType:NSStringAttributeType];
[grpNameExprDesc setName:@"grpName"];

// THIS COULD JUST BE an NSPropertyDescription if you want the WHOLE "grp":
NSPropertyDescription *grpPropDesc = [[[[self.moModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"RGE"] propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"grp"];

// Create data fetching and set its properties
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"RGE"];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: grpNameExprDesc, nil]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:grpNameExprDesc, countExprDesc, nil]];
[request setPredicate:filterQuery];


NSArray *results = [self.moContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"results = %@",results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using the "option 2" approach: [Grouping three entities with many-to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495166/grouping-three-entities-with-many-to-many-relationships)

Regards.
Pedro Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

I fetched all the groups, and for the display I did the following:

```
Group *gr = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSSet *filtered = [NSSet set];
if ([gr.name isEqualToString:@"GroupA"]) {
   filtered = [gr.elements filteredSetUsingPredicate:
      [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any groups.name == %@", @"GroupB"]];
}
else if ([gr.name isEqualToString:@"GroupB"]) {
   filtered = [gr.elements filteredSetUsingPredicate:
      [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any groups.name == %@", @"GroupA"]];
}
else {
   filtered = [gr.elements filteredSetUsingPredicate:
      [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"any groups.name == %@ && any groups.name == %@", 
        @"GroupA", @"GroupB"]];
}
cell.textLabel.text = 
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has %d elements.", 
      gr.name, filtered.count] ;
```

This gives the correct counts as in your example. However, if there is an excluded group, it would still be listed with 0 elements.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But the use of Group A and B where just an example. It should be "parametric" (variable). I think I found a solution and I will update the question just in case I could be interesting for somebody

Comment: In this case, please post your solution as an **answer**.